# In a client-server environment, what are advantages of using WCF vs direct Entity Framework database access?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, client-server

I'm developing a system with several client computers and one server that hosts the central database. Each client performs its CRUD operations directly against the database using Entity Framework, over the local network. The only real challenge I have with this is versioning (EF migrations).

On the other hand, I have heard about a similar architecture where only an application server talks to the database, and clients use a WCF for all CRUD operations and never access the database directly.

What would be the advantages of taking the WCF approach? It seems like there would be twice as much development work for not too much payoff, not to mention poorer performance. And as far as versioning goes, you can't escape it; you now have to migrate EF *and* version your WCF service. But people must choose this architecture for a reason and I'm curious as to why.

Comment: `entity framework` and `wcf` are `apples` and `oranges`.  Not sure what you're really asking

Comment: @Kritner: to contrast between a client accessing the server's database directly (using EF or even raw SQL) vs. calling a method on a WCF service where the other end of that service does the talking to the database. It's a question of, essentially, is there anything wrong with just letting multiple clients access the database directly, or should DB access be abstracted behind some high-level comms interface?

Comment: My experience is, if you hide the persistent layer behind an abstraction layer,WCF, Repsitory or what ever the implementation is, you lose the power/capabilities of the ORM.

Comment: Good point. However, I'm already abstracting away even EF behind the Repository pattern. The question now is, is there an advantage to going one step further with WCF? It's a lot of extra work, so those who do it must have good reasons for doing so.

Comment: A common use is when you cannot use trusted connection to authenticate users with database server, you use WCF to centralize database access with a domain account acting as the identity of the application pool for the service.

Comment: Ah that's exactly the kind of reason I was looking for--thanks

Comment: Good to help, just keep in mind that WCF is not the only way to accomplish this, if I'm going to make such implementation, I would go RESTful with Web API.

Answer (score 1):

For me most important difference between centralized and distributed database access is possibility to optimize use of connection pooling (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

SQL server has limited number of simultaneously open connections (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx). If you use connection pool in each of your applications (it is by default in EF) once opened connection is returned to pool instead of close. Then you will end up with i.e. 10 opened connection in each of your working applications.